# mongodb find by comparing field values

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to express the following SQL query in mongodb:

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t WHERE t.field1 > t.filed2;
```

**edit:**
To summarize:.

1. using a third field storing "field1 - field2" is almost perfect, but requires a little extra maintenance.
2. $where will load and eval in JavaScript and won't use any indexes. No good for large data.
3. map/reduce has the same problem and will go trough all records even if we need only one

Comment: I don't want to start a flame war but gosh, I hate noSQL so much.

Comment: then don't use it if you don't know where and how to use it properly. NoSQL is NOT a replacement for relational databases!

Comment: This is the source of my frustration. Most people refer to it as if it is a replacement. I see more and more comparisons along the lines of old (relational) vs modern (noSQL) data stores.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this using [$where](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B$where%7D%7D):

```
db.coll.find( { $where: "this.field1 > this.field2" } );
```

**But:**

> Javascript executes more slowly than
>   the native operators, but it is very flexible

If performance is an issue better to go with way suggested by @yi_H.

Comment: Using $where is never recommendable. The answer of yi_H is the correct one!

Comment: @Sentinel: Have you read my answer to the end before voting down????? I said that javascript working slow and better to create extra field as @yi_H suggested. But in any way $where operator exists i am absolutely sure that it can be used in some situations when performance not issue.

Comment: Use this only if you have a small collection or pre-filtered the collection with other conditions (which use indexes and return a small sub-set of the collection). Mongo has no idea how to speed up this query and will execute a full table scan.

Comment: @yi_H: Yeah, i know about full table scan. Thanks for clarification in any way.

Comment: No its not. That's the reason why we not programing in assembly anymore.

Answer (score 15):

You could store in your document `field1 - field2` as `field3`, then search for `{ field3: { $gt: 0 } }`

It also possible to get matching documents with mapreduce.

Comment: I should have mentioned that you can store the boolean value, which is performance wise better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a $where. Just be aware it will be fairly slow (has to execute Javascript code on every record) so combine with indexed queries if you can.

```
db.T.find( { $where: function() { return this.Grade1 > this.Grade2 } } );
```

or more compact:

```
db.T.find( { $where : "this.Grade1 > this.Grade2" } );
```