# Bash test and execute if directory pattern exists

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do you do an inline test for the existence of a directory pattern?

If a directory pattern exists, then I want to chmod that pattern.

e.g. I'm trying to do the following:

```
[ -d /usr/local/myproject/*/bin ] && chmod +x /usr/local/myproject/*/bin/*
```

but this gives me the error "-bash: [: too many arguments".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there's no need to test:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/myproject/*/bin/* 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: You know, thats even better. I initially was going "Too many arguments? Find to the rescue!" But my solution here won't help that if there are a lot of directories matched. tl;dr @yi_H is right and you should give him a cookie.

Comment: has @yi_H disappeared? Found another place where their answer was suggested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399426/mongodb-find-by-comparing-field-values

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because `-d` test takes one argument. You seem to be passing more than one. A fix would be:

```
for dir in /usr/local/myproject/*/bin; do
    [[ -d $dir ]] && chmod +x $dir/*
done
```

Answer (score 1):

To salvage some usefulness out of my answer, just suppose you had too many bin directories that you couldn't do it yi_H's way.

```
find /usr/local/myproject/ -path '/usr/local/myproject/*/bin' -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec chmod a+x {} + 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: The goal I'm trying to achieve is to not throw an error (return code 1) if the directory pattern does not exist. This still throws an error if the pattern does not exist.

Comment: @Cerin: The updated version won't. Also, why do you care? Just suppress the error. If it's the return code you dislike add `|| true`

Comment: I'm running this inside another application that I don't have full control over, and therefore can't easily modify it to ignore the return code.