# Searching a collection on parts of values

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Suppose I have a collection C with items with a property X. Suppose the values of X are themselves objects, list `{a:1, b: 2, c: 3}`. Can I find (or findOne) on C asking for items whose X property has a value whose a property `== 1`? I'd like to write `C.find({X.a: 1})`. Or maybe

```
C.find({X: function(value) { 
              return value.a == 1; 
           }
       });
```

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399426/mongodb-find-by-comparing-field-values ?

Comment: C.find({X.a: 1}) sounds correct, do you have a full example of the document you are querying?

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudo code just needs quotes around the property for mongo to understand it.  `C.find({'X.a': 1})` would return any document where X.a equalled 1.

The key words if you want to learn more are 'subdocuments' and 'dot notation' as described [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#exact-match-on-subdocument).

Answer (score 0):

You can use dot notation to access the elements in nested documents but you will need to do $unwind if you need to access elements within a list and then check if X.a equals 1.